# How to corrupt the EXT4 filesystem

Tags: kernel, filesystem, ext4

How to corrupt the EXT4 filesystem apart from corrupting the superblock ?

Regards
Chinmoy

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about recovering `dd` ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) has some examples) is  a tool to do a block transfer utility so can be used to create copies of filesystems but also alter the one you are working with.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/{blockdevice} count={blockstowrite} bs={sizeofblocks} seek={wheretostart}
```

This bypasses the filesystem so will mess up the journaling. A `bs=1k seek=10 count=4k` will make the partition or disk unusable until repaired with e2fsck.

And I assume everyone knows it is a bad idea to do this on anything that contains something that needs to be saved 1st.

---

Oh it can be as simple as using a hexeditor to edit a bit on a raw device.